# IPC between multiple processes on multiple servers

Tags: architecture, networking, service, ipc, messaging

Let's say you have 2 servers each with 8 CPU cores each.

The servers each run 8 network services that each host an arbitrary number of long-lived TCP/IP client connections.

Clients send messages to the services.

The services *do something* based on the messages, and potentially notify N>1 of the clients of state changes.

Sure, it sounds like a botnet but it isn't.  Consider how IRC works with c2s and s2s connections and s2s message relaying.

- The servers are in the same data center.
- The servers can communicate over a private VLAN @1GigE.
- Messages are < 1KB in size.

*How would you coordinate which services on which host should receive and relay messages to connected clients for state change messages?*

There's an infinite number of ways to solve this problem efficiently.

- AMQP (RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, etc.)
- Spread Toolkit
- N^2 connections between allservices (bad)
- Heck, even run IRC!
- ...

I'm looking for a solution that:

- perhaps exploits the fact that there's only a small closed cluster
- is easy to admin
- scales well
- is "dumb" (no weird edge cases)

What are your experiences?

What do you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about raw ethernet broadcasting and filtering on client side?